# How do I obtain the favicon of a website?

Tags: favicon

How to get an icon from address bar of Opera, I.E. and other browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question us not specific

1. if you want to download that icon
   then you can try
   domainname.com/favicon.ico, if that
   doesnot work then view the source
   code of the page on the
   `<html><head>` section search for
   `link rel="shortcut icon"`.
   following is the favicon for
   stackoverflow

   ```
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">
   ```
2. If you want to put such icon for
   your website then put a ico file in
   root folder of you document root or
   link each page above code in
    section with href to
   your icon file, preferably (16X16)
   or (32X32)

Answer (score 1):

The icon is called [favicon.ico](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon).

Put a .ico file in the root web directory.